Посмотреть под нагрузкой, как Java приложение загружает ядра процессора
Возникла задача: посмотреть, на сколько микросервис загружает каждое ядро процессора под сильной нагрузкой. Нагрузка делается при помощи JMeter. Я для профилирования использую VisualVM, но она не отображает ядра процессора. Есть еще какой-то софт, который решает такую задачу?
